# Google Fusion Table SQL query where clause - only AND works, not OR?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT * FROM 1910640 WHERE stype='P' OR stype='ERC' OR stype='PERC' ORDER BY ST_DISTANCE(geometry, LATLNG(-0.12623619999999391,51.5001524)) LIMIT 6
```

This results in a "parseerror". If I replace OR with AND the query returns success:

```
SELECT * FROM 1910640 WHERE stype='P' AND stype='ERC' AND stype='PERC' ORDER BY ST_DISTANCE(geometry, LATLNG(-0.12623619999999391,51.5001524)) LIMIT 6
```

Anyone else ran into this with Fusion Tables and have a solution/workaround?

The API doc does imply only AND is allowed, which came as a big surprise to me.
http://code.google.com/apis/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide.html#Querying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OR isn't supported - look at the API ref filter_conditions

IN is supported - so you can IN all your OR conditions for SType

Comment: Thanks!

The subsequent query, if anyone else hasn't needed to use IN before:

    SELECT * FROM 1910640 WHERE stype IN ('P', 'ERC', 'PERC' )  ORDER BY ST_DISTANCE(geometry, LATLNG(-0.12623619999999391,51.5001524)) LIMIT 6

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me if I'm saying foolery, since I never have use fusion-tables, but `OR` queries can be split into 2 queries, one for each condition.

The main problem in this workaround is that you must implement the ORDER in programming language when merging both queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN instead of OR because OR is not supported by fusion tables.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp